# Localsettings or where to put an URI in a Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, appsettings

I'm developing a Windows 8.1. Store app with .Net Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

This is the first time I develop a Windows 8.1 Store app and I'm not sure where to put an URI.

This URI is for a Web service and in another apps I will use App.config to store it.

On WinRT app I have found [localsettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings) but I'm not sure if this is what I have to use.

In other words. Imagine that I'm developing Windows 8.1 Store Facebook App and I need to know where Facebook Web Services are (their URI). Where do you store that URI?

Any advice?

Comment: What are you using this Uri for? Is it in code? Where are you getting it? Is it being generated at runtime and you need to store it for later? Does it need to follow the user from system to system? Is it only for the local system? Is it only for the local user?

Comment: I have added an example in my question. For example, Facebook Windows Store app needs to know Facebook's Web Service URI. Where is that URI Stored?

Comment: There are a couple of ways you can do this. You can include it in a Resources file in the app and use a ResourceLoader to retrieve it. This is dually helpful as you can have different resources for different cultures/languages (so in the case of Facebook the ResourceLoader will return facebook.com/en vs facebook.com/fr based on the language). If it's a static, constant string you can also just create a `public const` field somewhere. Make a class, `ApiUris` and have `public const Uri BaseServiceUri = new Uri("my address");`. Then retrieve it with `ApiUris.BaseServiceUri` in code. Both work.

Comment: One note is for the ResourceLoader, you'll have to convert it from a String to a Uri. This is trivial to do in most cases though, and in the case of DependencyProperties generally happens automatically.